# Replace kwallet with gnome seahorse

Tags: password, kde, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and I have recently installed `kde` desktop.
When I was on `unity` desktop the `seahorse` application was used to prompting me for main password at startup to unlock the keyring and let my applications  access my passwords.

Now on `kde` it does not prompt anything at startup. I think the reason is that the default keyring is `kwallet`.

Is it possible to replace / disable `kwallet` and set gnome `seahorse` as default?

Thanks